# PhpStorm, ignore certain tags in error checking?

Tags: syntax, phpstorm

I'm using [CouchCMS](http://www.couchcms.com/) which is a brilliant little inline CMS.  It requires custom tags for many of the features like `<cms:editable></cms:editable>`

PhpStorm keeps telling me these are not valid (I think that's what it's trying to say anyway)

[image]

[image]

They all show up as a red line on the scrollbar and show as errors in the analysis.  How can I tell PhpStorm this is okay?

It throws a different error for the `<cms:template>` tag since it's before the doctype.

Comment: I tried using `alt+enter` to "auto fix" by typing in a namespace.  I tried a few things but still couldn't get it to go away.

Comment: Please provide sample of such file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Inspections`
2. Expand `XML`
3. Uncheck `Unbound XML namespace prefix`